# How to get count from resultset?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) FROM `users`");
```

in MySQL i have answer "5" , how to get this 5 from resultset in java? int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it as an int column :

```
int count = -1;
if (rs.next()) {
    count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try aliasing the COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`), then retrieving the alias from the ResultSet. This will be more readable and easier to maintain if you end up adding more logic to the query later.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) as NUM_ROWS FROM `users`");

int count = -1;
if(rs.next())
{
    count = rs.getInt("NUM_ROWS");

}
```